# Qt: showFullScreen() on a QWidget doesn't remove Mac OSX Menu Bar

Tags: qt

We get our application full screen alright, but the OSX Menu bar is still shown above it...

Is there any way around this problem?

Comment: Possibly a known bug: https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-2790

Answer (score 0):

Yes, might be a bug as already suggested. Try with FramelessWindowHint, like this:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QLabel label("Test!");
    label.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    label.showFullScreen();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I tested it on Mac OS X 10.7.1 (which is not even supported) and seems to work.